# Pycharm and .rst --- NameError: Cannot find docutils in selected interpreter

Tags: pycharm, restructuredtext

I'm new to Pycharm as well as writing `.rst` files. I'm currently trying to debug some issue that prevents my `.rst` file from rendering properly. I want to use the `.rst` preview that Pycharm provides, but I get this error:

```
NameError: Cannot find docutils in selected interpreter.
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I've installed the `rst2html` interpreter on my project, applied it and restarted Pycharm, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: `rst2html` is a package, not an interpreter. A Python interpreter should be in your virtual environment, along with other packages, including `docutils`. First become familiar with these terms in PyCharm's Help, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to `~/.profile` file for it to correctly export your locale settings.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

These two lines added to the file should suffice to set the locale [replace `en_US` for your desired locale, and check beforehand that it is indeed installed on your system (`locale -a`)].

After that, you can start a new session and check using `locale`:

```
$ locale
```

The following should be the output:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then restart PyCharm. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: This solution works and should probably be accepted.

Comment: if you're using `zsh`, open your  `~/.zshrc` and uncomment `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, then restart pycharm again.

Answer (score 3):

There's an [open bug for this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31005) open since July 2018 (and still open as of September 2019). It seems that a workaround for at least some people (including me) is to launch PyCharm from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on OSX) I had to install `docutils` on my global python installation.
I had to:

1. Make sure that in `Settings -> Project -> Interpreter` only one version of Python (outside of the virtual envs) was available (by removing [Pressing "-" below the list] the linked Python 2.7 version).
2. Forcing global install of docutils `sudo /usr/bin/pip3 install docutils`
3. Restart PyCharm, make sure your project have the correct interpreter